# Another ordering on the set of real numbers

Tags: order-theory, real-numbers

Is there a total order relation on the set of real numbers that is compatible with the field structure but does not satisfy the completeness for the associated order topology?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. The ordering of $\mathbb{R}$ compatible with the field structure is unique.

In fact, assume we have another ordering $\succ$ such that $0\succ a$ for some $a$ that is positive in the standard order. Then we have $a=b^2$ for some $b$, which means $0\succ b^2$ but either $b$ or $-b$ is positive with respect to $\succ$, so we have $b^2=(-b)^2\succ 0$. This is a contradiction.

Comment: You can avoid contradiction; if $\prec$ is a field ordering then every nonzero square is $\prec$-positive, in general. So, if $0<a=b^2$, we get $0\prec a=b^2$. If $a<0$, then $0<-a$, so $0\prec -a$ and therefore $a\prec 0$.

Comment: @egreg Thanks. But I think I have written more or less the same thing.